# How I can unwrap key and value objects in java Map using Jackson anotations?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have bean like this

```
public class PickupDate {

    private LocalDate date;
}
```

I want to serialize Map<PickupDate, Integer> object to

```
{
  "2020-07-17": 1
}
```

not to

```
{
  "PickupDate@1ecd0470[date=2019-12-01]": {
    "capacity": 0
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite the toString() method of PickupDate. Capacity comes from some other object that you have. It would be more clear if you provided the actual code.

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<PickupDate, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(new PickupDate(LocalDate.now()), 1);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
}
```

Pickup:

```
class PickupDate {
private LocalDate date;
public PickupDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}

//Here you put whatever you want to be in the JSON
@Override
public String toString() {
    return date.toString();
}
}
```

Result: `{"2020-07-16":1}`

Whatever is returned from the `toString()` method, is written in the JSON. So, if you want to change the date format or anything else, you have to do it there.